# What's going on with this bizarre recursive type error in Rust?

Tags: types, reference, rust, type-inference

I have an iterable struct called `Join`:

```
use std::iter::Peekable;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Join<T, S> {
    container: T,
    separator: S,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum JoinItem<T, S> {
    Element(T),
    Separator(S),
}

pub struct JoinIter<Iter: Iterator, Sep> {
    iter: Peekable<Iter>,
    sep: Sep,
    next_sep: bool,
}

impl<Iter: Iterator, Sep> JoinIter<Iter, Sep> {
    fn new(iter: Iter, sep: Sep) -> Self {
        JoinIter {
            iter: iter.peekable(),
            sep,
            next_sep: false,
        }
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator, S: Clone> Iterator for JoinIter<I, S> {
    type Item = JoinItem<I::Item, S>;

    /// Advance to the next item in the Join. This will either be the next
    /// element in the underlying iterator, or a clone of the separator.
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let sep = &self.sep;
        let next_sep = &mut self.next_sep;

        if *next_sep {
            self.iter.peek().map(|_| {
                *next_sep = false;
                JoinItem::Separator(sep.clone())
            })
        } else {
            self.iter.next().map(|element| {
                *next_sep = true;
                JoinItem::Element(element)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

A reference to `Join` implements `IntoIterator`:

```
impl<'a, T, S> IntoIterator for &'a Join<T, S>
where
    &'a T: IntoIterator,
{
    type IntoIter = JoinIter<<&'a T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, &'a S>;
    type Item = JoinItem<<&'a T as IntoIterator>::Item, &'a S>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        JoinIter::new(self.container.into_iter(), &self.separator)
    }
}
```

This compiles and passes usage tests.

I also have an `iter` method defined on my `Join` struct:

```
impl<T, S> Join<T, S>
where
    for<'a> &'a T: IntoIterator,
{
    pub fn iter(&self) -> JoinIter<<&T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, &S> {
        self.into_iter()
    }
}
```

This compiles fine, but when I actually try to use it:

```
fn main() {
    // Create a join struct
    let join = Join {
        container: vec![1, 2, 3],
        separator: ", ",
    };

    // This works fine
    let mut good_ref_iter = (&join).into_iter();
    assert_eq!(good_ref_iter.next(), Some(JoinItem::Element(&1)));
    assert_eq!(good_ref_iter.next(), Some(JoinItem::Separator(&", ")));
    assert_eq!(good_ref_iter.next(), Some(JoinItem::Element(&2)));
    assert_eq!(good_ref_iter.next(), Some(JoinItem::Separator(&", ")));
    assert_eq!(good_ref_iter.next(), Some(JoinItem::Element(&3)));
    assert_eq!(good_ref_iter.next(), None);

    // This line fails to compile; comment out this section and it all works
    let bad_ref_iter = join.iter();
    assert_eq!(bad_ref_iter.next(), Some(JoinItem::Element(&1)));
    assert_eq!(bad_ref_iter.next(), Some(JoinItem::Separator(&", ")));
    assert_eq!(bad_ref_iter.next(), Some(JoinItem::Element(&2)));
    assert_eq!(bad_ref_iter.next(), Some(JoinItem::Separator(&", ")));
    assert_eq!(bad_ref_iter.next(), Some(JoinItem::Element(&3)));
    assert_eq!(bad_ref_iter.next(), None);
}
```

I get some kind of weird type recursion error:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `&_: std::marker::Sized`
   --> src/join.rs:288:29
    |
 96 |         let mut iter = join.iter();
    |                             ^^^^
    |
    = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="128"]` attribute to your crate
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `&_`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `&join::Join<_, _>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `&join::Join<join::Join<_, _>, _>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `&join::Join<join::Join<join::Join<_, _>, _>, _>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `&join::Join<join::Join<join::Join<join::Join<_, _>, _>, _>, _>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `&join::Join<join::Join<join::Join<join::Join<join::Join<_, _>, _>, _>, _>, _>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `&join::Join<join::Join<join::Join<join::Join<join::Join<join::Join<_, _>, _>, _>, _>, _>, _>`
...
```

(I redacted about 100 more lines of recursive type error in the ...)

As best I can tell, it appears to be attempting to proactively evaluate whether `&Join<_, _>` implements `IntoIterator`, which requires checking if `&Join<Join<_, _>, _>` fulfills IntoIterator, and so on forever. What I can't figure out is why it thinks it has to do this, since my actual type is fully qualified as `Join<Vec<{integer}, &'static str>`. Some things I've tried:

- Moving the trait bound off of the impl header and into the `iter` function, like so:

  ```
  fn iter(&'a self) -> JoinIter<<&'a T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, &'a S>
  where &'a T: IntoIterator
  ```

  This has the same result.
- Replacing `self.into_iter()` with the underlying expression, `JoinIter::new(self.container.into_iter(), self.separator)`, in the hopes that maybe it's struggling to differentiate `self.into_iter()` from `(&self).into_iter()`. I've tried all of the following patterns:

  - `fn iter(&self) -> ... { self.into_iter() }`
  - `fn iter(&self) -> ... { (&self).into_iter() }`
  - `fn iter(&self) -> ... { JoinIter::new(self.container.into_iter(), &self.separator) }`
  - `fn iter(&self) -> ... { JoinIter::new((&self.container).into_iter(), &self.separator) }`
- Speaking of which, replacing the call to `self.iter()` with `(&self).into_iter()` fixes the problem, but replacing it with `(&self).iter()` does not.

Why does `(&join).into_iter()` work, but `join.iter()` does not, even though `iter()` simply calls `self.into_iter()` under the hood?

This complete example, with identical code, is also available in the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=4a48b1df26336392de8a267a95f056b0)

---

For more context about `Join`, see my older [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53364798/864406) and my actual [source code](https://github.com/Lucretiel/joinery/blob/9bc3b2ddaa2609e7f9a9bc499555255eff2c334b/src/iter.rs).

Comment: @Lucretiel I've reduced the [playground example to a fraction of its size](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=f107e16e3daf793f846800c494799418). Note that removing the empty `impl` block makes the error go away. This gives some clues why it is occurring, but I don't really have an explanation yet. Also note that the line triggering the error now is `let _ = join;`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach that microexample has the same error as my code, but doesn't reproduce my specific issue. In my code, `IntoIterator` DOES work fine; it's the `fn iter()` (which literally just calls `into_iter()`) that inexplicably breaks

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the compiler is not able to resolve the trait requirement needed by `iter()` return type `JoinIter<<&T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, &S>`.

I've received an hint for this from `rustc --explain E0275` error explanation:

> This error occurs when there was a recursive trait requirement that overflowed
>   before it could be evaluated. Often this means that there is unbounded
>   recursion in resolving some type bounds.

I don't know the details of the inference process of rust, I imagine the following is happening.

Take this signature:

```
fn iter(&self) -> JoinIter<<&T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, &S>
```

The compiler try to infer the return type from:

```
JoinIter<<&T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, &S>
```

but `<&T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter` is inferred from the `&'a Join` impl:

```
impl<'a, T, S> IntoIterator for &'a Join<T, S>
    where &'a T: IntoIterator
{
    type IntoIter = JoinIter<<&'a T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, &'a S>;
    type Item = JoinItem<<&'a T as IntoIterator>::Item, &'a S>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        JoinIter::new(self.container.into_iter(), &self.separator)
    }
}
```

and `IntoIter` is again a `JoinIter<<&'a T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, &'a S>` that has an `IntoIter` and so and so ad infinitum.

A way to make it compile it is to help the compiler with a [turbofish](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/generics.html#resolving-ambiguities):

```
let mut bad_ref_iter = Join::<Vec<i32>, &str>::iter(&join);
```

instead of:

```
let bad_ref_iter = join.iter();
```

### Update

The line:

```
type IntoIter = JoinIter<<&'a T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, &'a S>;
```

generate a recursion because Rust checks that traits are valid when they are defined rather than when they are used.

See [this post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/strange-rust-compiler-recursion/22543) for some more details and pointers to the progress of work
of lazy normalization, which may solve this problem.

Comment: I still don't have any clue where the infinite recursion is coming from. Why does `<&T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter` need to be "inferred"? My understanding is the `T` and `S` are inferred from the type of `join`, but once `T` is known, `<&T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter` is a complete type that does not require any inference. The work-around is nice, but the source of the problem remains a complete mystery to me.

Comment: Could be that the recursion happens before `T` and `S` are inferred from `join`?
Look at [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=0b46b9a5f617d3e7e7e6d2bb0b2740d0)

Comment: cross-posted [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/strange-rust-compiler-recursion/22543)