# How to add a trait bound to a generic associated type?

Tags: rust, generic-associated-types

Recently, [the post "The push for GATs stabilization"](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/08/03/GATs-stabilization-push.html) was published on the Rust blog. I'm interested in the `LendingIterator` trait but hit a problem when trying to use it. This is the definition from the post:

```
trait LendingIterator {
    type Item<'a> where Self: 'a;
    fn next<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item<'a>>;
}
```

All the things advertised in the blog post work fine and I see how GATs help in several ways. But: **how do you add a trait bound to the associated `Item` type?**

With the standard `Iterator` trait, it's easy:

```
fn print_all<I>(mut i: I) 
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: std::fmt::Debug,    // <-------
{
    while let Some(x) = i.next() {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }
}
```

But with the new trait, the bound this bound does not compile ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=555b3edcacf1e94cd7c467f6892aeeba)):

```
where
    I: LendingIterator,
    I::Item: std::fmt::Debug,
```

Compiler says:

```
error[E0107]: missing generics for associated type `LendingIterator::Item`
  --> src/lib.rs:12:8
   |
12 |     I::Item: std::fmt::Debug,
   |        ^^^^ expected 1 lifetime argument
   |
note: associated type defined here, with 1 lifetime parameter: `'a`
  --> src/lib.rs:5:10
   |
5  |     type Item<'a> where Self: 'a;
   |          ^^^^ --
help: add missing lifetime argument
   |
12 |     I::Item<'a>: std::fmt::Debug,
   |        ^^^^^^^^
```

So we need a lifetime parameter somehow. Apart from just using `'static` (which is overly restrictive), I see two ways to achieve that. However, both have subtle but significant disadvantages/problems.

### Lifetime parameter on function

```
fn print_all<'a, I>(mut i: I) 
where
    I: 'a + LendingIterator,
    I::Item<'a>: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    while let Some(x) = i.next() {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=199643ee12304fb45c9d83946a423bf4))

This fails to compile with:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `i` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:14:25
   |
9  | fn print_all<'a, I>(mut i: I) 
   |              -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
14 |     while let Some(x) = i.next() {
   |                         ^-------
   |                         |
   |                         `i` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
   |                         argument requires that `i` is borrowed for `'a`
```

The reason for this is that lifetime parameters (actually, all generic parameters) of `print_all` are chosen by the caller. This implies that the lifetime is larger than the scope of `print_all`: the caller cannot know of any lifetime that is just inside of `print_all`. That means that the call to `next` has to borrow `i` for the whole lifetime `'a`. But that includes all of `print_all`, so we can only borrow exactly once!

In any case, this solution is not viable.

### Higher kinded trait bounds (♥y bois)

```
fn print_all<I>(mut i: I) 
where
    I: LendingIterator,
    for<'a> I::Item<'a>: std::fmt::Debug,
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c62b5d3ea41a2d7f828517818bdf32a4))

Hey, it compiles! However, there is a subtle problem with it. Lets take the `WindowsMut` iterator from the blog post and try to pass it to `print_all`: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=efcd576fb9d6f18184e175133ed2fafd). It does not compile:

```
error[E0277]: `<_ as LendingIterator>::Item<'a>` doesn't implement `Debug`
  --> src/main.rs:43:5
   |
9  | fn print_all<I>(mut i: I) 
   |    --------- required by a bound in this
...
12 |     for<'a> I::Item<'a>: std::fmt::Debug,
   |                          --------------- required by this bound in `print_all`
...
43 |     print_all(windows);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ `<_ as LendingIterator>::Item<'a>` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `Debug`
   |
   = help: the trait `for<'a> Debug` is not implemented for `<_ as LendingIterator>::Item<'a>`
```

Strange! Remember:

```
type Item<'a> where Self: 'a = &'a mut [T];
```

And `std::fmt::Debug` is definitely implemented for mutable references to slices. Regardless of lifetime. ([Compared the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html)).

I think that the bound is not satisfied because `for<'a>` means "for all possible lifetimes", which includes `'static`. Let's write that out:

Does `WindowsMut<'t, T>::Item<'a>` implement `Debug` for all possible `'a`s? Does `WindowsMut<'t, T>::Item<'static>` implement `Debug`? That's `&'static mut [T]`. That type is only valid if `T: 'static`. And there is also this weird `where Self: 'a` bound. And `WindowsMut<'t, T>: 'static` is definitely not satisfied unless `'t == 'static`.

---

**How do I properly add a bound to the `Item` type of `LendingIterator` and implement `print_all`?** This should be possible, right? Has this problem been discussed already? Is my reasoning above incorrect, in particular regarding the HRTBs?

Comment: Part of the problem seems to be explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364798/why-does-the-compiler-claim-that-an-associated-type-from-a-higher-ranked-trait-b), and implementing the private module can help us get rid of it complaining about `Debug` not being implemented. But then the function is requiring that `arr` have `'static` lifetime. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=18c87d3d23edb6452a9c743292970204)

Answer (score 1):

I see your reasoning why this this pattern should extend, but isn't this maybe just a limitation of GATs at the moment (or just a bug)? Though, you can refactor your trait bound farther up the chain for this to work just fine by requiring ...

```rust
trait LendingIterator {
    type Item<'a>: std::fmt::Debug where Self: 'a; // Require Debug trait
    fn next<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item<'a>>;
}

// Require T has Debug trait
impl<'t, T: std::fmt::Debug> LendingIterator for WindowsMut<'t, T> {
    type Item<'a> where Self: 'a = &'a mut [T];
    
    fn next<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item<'a>> {
        let retval = self.slice[self.start..].get_mut(..self.window_size)?;
        self.start += 1;
        Some(retval)
    }
}
```

and removing your bound on the function ...

```rust
fn print_all<I>(mut i: I) 
where
    I: LendingIterator,
    // Remove 
    // for<'a> I::Item<'a>: std::fmt::Debug, 
{
    while let Some(x) = i.next() {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }
}
```

But if I then un-remove the trait bound, I get a different error than you had before ...

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'a> <WindowsMut<'_, {integer}> as LendingIterator>::Item<'a> == <WindowsMut<'_, {integer}> as LendingIterator>::Item<'a>`
  --> src/main.rs:45:5
   |
9  | fn print_all<I>(mut i: I) 
   |    --------- required by a bound in this
...
13 |     for<'a> I::Item<'a>: std::fmt::Debug, 
   |                          --------------- required by this bound in `print_all`
...
45 |     print_all(windows);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found `&mut [_]`
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<WindowsMut<'_, {integer}> as LendingIterator>::Item<'a>`
            found mutable reference `&'a mut [{integer}]`
   = help: consider constraining the associated type `<WindowsMut<'_, {integer}> as LendingIterator>::Item<'a>` to `&'a mut [_]` or calling a method that returns `<WindowsMut<'_, {integer}> as LendingIterator>::Item<'a>`
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0271`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

I would think that this additional trait bound is a tautology to the others, which to me is a red flag the compiler is complaining for no reason.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=07d33109a3083db566af9c41940041ec) to show the example works.